# FreeSWITCH TLS error in 'Client Hello' Request

Tags: ssl, freeswitch

I am trying to setup FreeSWITCH with TLS,

It is the Sofia status :

> internal   profile   sip:mod_sofia@172.16.250.7:5060      RUNNING (0)
>
> internal   profile   sip:mod_sofia@172.16.250.7:5061      RUNNING (0) (TLS)

the port for TLS is ok and up.

I can connect with TLS with FSClient.

When I use a SIP phone , 3CX or EyeBeam I cannot connect to this server.

I have installed cafile.pem in both windows client and SoftPhone as a trusted root certificate but there is a problem in the NEGOTIATING procedure :

> tport.c:2754 tport_wakeup_pri() tport_wakeup_pri(0xb6c0ce38): events IN
>   tport.c:869 tport_alloc_secondary() tport_alloc_secondary(0xb6c0ce38): new secondary tport 0xb6c20dc8
>   tport_type_tls.c:607 tport_tls_accept() tport_tls_accept(0xb6c20dc8): new connection from tls/172.16.250.181:32741/sips
>   tport_tls.c:873 tls_connect() tls_connect(0xb6c20dc8): events NEGOTIATING
>   tport_tls.c:908 tls_connect() tls_connect(0xb6c20dc8): self->tp_accepted : 1 , ret : -1.
>   tport_tls.c:965 tls_connect() tls_connect(0xb6c20dc8): TLS setup failed (error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)) 
>   tport.c:2095 tport_close() tport_close(0xb6c20dc8): tls/172.16.250.181:32741/sips 
>   tport.c:2268 tport_set_secondary_timer() tport(0xb6c20dc8): set timer at 0 ms because zap

I used with WireShark to sniff packets and what I found is that 'Hello Client' request by FSClient has different size and extensions compare to the one sent by 3CX.
3CX does not specify any extensions which is obviously is not mandatory.

FSClient Sends this request packet :

> Secure Sockets Layer
>      TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello 
>          Content Type: Handshake (22) 
>          Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301) 
>          Length: 195 
>          Handshake Protocol: Client Hello 
>              Handshake Type: Client Hello (1) 
>              Length: 191 
>              Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301) 
>              Random 
>                  gmt_unix_time: Dec  4, 2013 15:15:52.000000000 Iran Standard Time 
>                  random_bytes: fc7d8f292251a0e81da8e7ed81182027805acf20ac036386... 
>              Session ID Length: 0 
>              Cipher Suites Length: 82 
>              Cipher Suites (41 suites) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0088) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0087) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc019) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00f) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc005) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0084) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013) 
>                  Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc017) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc00d) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc003) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x009a) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0099) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0045) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0044) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc018) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0096) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0041) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (0x0007) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc016) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc00c) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc002) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff) 
>               Compression Methods Length: 1 
>               Compression Methods (1 method) 
>                   Compression Method: null (0) 
>               Extensions Length: 68 
>               Extension: ec_point_formats 
>                   Type: ec_point_formats (0x000b) 
>                   Length: 4 
>                   EC point formats Length: 3 
>                   Elliptic curves point formats (3) 
>                       EC point format: uncompressed (0) 
>                       EC point format: ansiX962_compressed_prime (1) 
>                       EC point format: ansiX962_compressed_char2 (2) 
>               Extension: elliptic_curves 
>                   Type: elliptic_curves (0x000a) 
>                   Length: 52 
>                   Elliptic Curves Length: 50 
>                   Elliptic curves (25 curves) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect163k1 (0x0001) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect163r1 (0x0002) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect163r2 (0x0003) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect193r1 (0x0004) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect193r2 (0x0005) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect233k1 (0x0006) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect233r1 (0x0007) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect239k1 (0x0008) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect283k1 (0x0009) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect283r1 (0x000a) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect409k1 (0x000b) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect409r1 (0x000c) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect571k1 (0x000d) 
>                       Elliptic curve: sect571r1 (0x000e) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp160k1 (0x000f) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp160r1 (0x0010) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp160r2 (0x0011) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp192k1 (0x0012) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp192r1 (0x0013) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp224k1 (0x0014) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp224r1 (0x0015) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp256k1 (0x0016) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp256r1 (0x0017) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp384r1 (0x0018) 
>                       Elliptic curve: secp521r1 (0x0019) 
>               Extension: SessionTicket TLS 
>                   Type: SessionTicket TLS (0x0023) 
>                   Length: 0 
>                   Data (0 bytes)

3CX 'Hello Client' packet:

> Secure Sockets Layer 
>       TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello 
>           Content Type: Handshake (22) 
>           Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301) 
>           Length: 95 
>           Handshake Protocol: Client Hello 
>               Handshake Type: Client Hello (1) 
>               Length: 91 
>               Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301) 
>               Random 
>                   gmt_unix_time: Dec  4, 2013 15:30:15.000000000 Iran Standard Time 
>                   random_bytes: bea9192de02164ba455c963dd752aea54abc853fb0ef3934... 
>               Session ID Length: 0 
>               Cipher Suites Length: 52 
>               Cipher Suites (26 suites) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00f) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc00d) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc00c) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0015) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0014) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0009) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0008) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (0x0012) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA (0x0011) 
>                   Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 (0x0003) 
>               Compression Methods Length: 1 
>               Compression Methods (1 method) 
>                   Compression Method: null (0)

and there is resonse packet from Freeswitch :

> Secure Sockets Layer 
>   -    TLSv1 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure) 
>           Content Type: Alert (21) 
>           Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301) 
>           Length: 2 
>           Alert Message 
>               Level: Fatal (2) 
>               Description: Handshake Failure (40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert, but this is what helped me:

FSClient does TLS handshake with FS, with this `TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` cipher suites.

So, you have to check if your soft phone supports that. If not, try to download some older version of FS (1.0.6), and in the script dir compare `gentls_cert.in` with your `gentle_cert.in`. Modify changes, reverse to older version. You can see changes on GitHub. If this doesn't help you, look for solution in this script. I think there is the problem. I hope I help :)

Comment: Thank you for response, I've managed to solve the problem by generating cafile.pem and agent.pem with simpleCA (Self signed certificate). It seems gentls_cert have limited support for soft phones.